# ElectronでWebBluetoothを使いたい

Tags: bluetooth, electron

ElectronでWebBluetoothを使おうと思い、`navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice()`を呼び出したが`navigator.bluetooth`がなく、node-web-bluetoothもインストールできず、どうすればいいか困っています。

何か他に方法はないでしょうか。

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状、ElectronでWebBluetoothを使用するにはChromiumの `enable-experimental-web-platform-features` フラグが必要なようです。

[Event: 'select-bluetooth-device'](https://electronjs.org/docs/all#event-select-bluetooth-device) にあるようにappにフラグを立ててやればAPI自体は使えるようになるようです。

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let win = null
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-experimental-web-platform-features')

app.on('ready', () => {
  ...
```

まあ他にも壁がありそうですが……